# Where can I find large thru-hole heatsinks like this?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, design, heatsink

I'm doing a project with an OPA541 amplifier, and I need to find a heatsink similar to the one in the pictures: [image][image]
But I only found small ones with a screw hole and legs for soldering, none of the large ones have any holes or legs, I think the ones I saw are supposed to be glued on processors. But are heatsinks like this sold, or do I have to drill the holes myself, if I want one? Or am I looking at the wrong places?
Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: https://br.mouser.com/c/thermal-management/heat-sinks/?q=heatsink&mounting%20style=Through%20Hole

Comment: To the extent that this asks about where to purchase an item, it is off-topic on this site. Sorry.

Comment: look in mouser.com, rs-online, digikey etc.

Answer (score 3):

You buy heat sink extruded stock and drill it on a drill press then tap the hole. Don't forget to mechanically brace such a large heatsink to the PCB in a way other than the component. That might warrant additional tapped holes on the edge to screw into the PCB.

Center punch before drilling, especially on a thin edge. Do not use a hand drill.

Comment: Furthermore, small items like this need to be in a vise; they tend to become projectiles if hand-held.

Comment: @rdtsc You can do it by hand which lets the object move to allow the drill to find the center punch hole, but you need to use a safety stop bolted to the table so if the part grabs it does not go spinning and flung. But a vise not bolted to the table also allows movement for hunting while adding weight to resist catching and area to hold with your hands.

Answer (score 1):

OPA541 can dissipate quite a lot of power, 125W according to the datasheet, and the heat sink on the picture is way too small to exploit the opamp's capabilities. In addition, the PCB itself is in the way of the airflow. I don't think OPA541 has over-temperature protection.

In case you're interested, LM3886 or even LM1875 will produce a lot less distortion.

If you want to use a larger heatsink to use this opamp to its full potential, it will be too large to mount on a PCB. The solution is the usual, to mount the PCB on the heat sink with angle brackets (if mounted at right angle) or with threaded spacers (if mounted parallel to the heat sink). If fan noise is not a problem, a tunnel heat sink with a fan, or a PC CPU heatsink are also an option.

In all cases, the legs of the component will expand along with temperature cycling, and this can rip the pads off your PCB. So something needs to be able to flex. For example, you can make the PCB a bit wider and fasten it to the heat sink with angle brackets, so the PCB will flex as the component legs get a bit longer when hot. If you put the brackets right next to the opamp, the PCB won't be able to flex, and it will try to rip its pads. This problem also occurs with through-hole mounted heatsinks that are fastened to the PCB very close to the component pads.